# useReducer Cannot set properties of undefined after second attempt to edit the value

Tags: reactjs

For some reason combo of useReducer and useContext is not working out for me, as you can see from the code I'm trying to change the value using the onChange and it works for the first time but the second time everything crashes.
Here's link to the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-field-k7lif?file=/src/App.css
Ps: App.js , and Surcharge are the files to check out. (ignore the comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your reducer is never returning the updated state and is implicitly returning `undefined`.

```
function reducer(state, newState) {
  switch (newState.type) {
    case "calcCartValue":
      state.cartValue = newState.value;
  }
}
```

Should be

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "calcCartValue":
      return { ...state, cartValue: action.value };
    default:
      throw new Error(`${action.type} action is not supported`);
  }
}
```

I suggest taking another look at the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: Perhaps, but I still can't type a word is there something wrong with the value attribute in Surcharge.js input field ?

Comment: Yes, let me send you my forked code sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bell-d58ll

Comment: Basically your value is hardcoded in the Surcharge component and should reflect what's on the state

Comment: value={surContext.initialState.cartValue}
 

changed to this still doesn't work like it should? Am I missing the point here ?

Comment: yeah the initial state never changes so you are still hardcoding the value, if you notice you never change what initialValue is so of course the input will hold that value no matter what you type. When you type in the form you call a state update which will change the cartValue, that change needs to be reflected in the input and to do so you need to pass that state to that component. That's what I did in the codesandbox I shared before.

Comment: Got it , finally !

Answer (score 0):

<ContextOne.Provider value={{ initialState, dispatch }}>
Naturally, initialState never changes and is, in fact, just the initial state, so all zeroes. What I needed to do was this:

<ContextOne.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>

Answer (score 0):

In app.js you should change this line :

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
<ContextOne.Provider
    value={{ initialState: initialState, dispatch: dispatch }}
  >
.....
```

to this

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
<ContextOne.Provider
    value={{ initialState: state, dispatch: dispatch }}
  >
.....
```

And also, in Surcharge.js at input value prop change this:

```
<input
    value="0"
.....
```

to this

```
<input
    value={surContext.initialState.cartValue}
.....
```